# How to add Ajax loader to Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a simple manual slideshow.I want to add ajax loader image when i click Previews or Next button for all time before load Test 1, Test 2, Test 3 texts.
Any help to do it

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <button class="" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
 <button class="" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
 
 <div class="mySlides">Test 1</div>
 <div class="mySlides">Test 2</div>
 <div class="mySlides">Test 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ajax loader? You want to load an image using ajax? You don't need ajax. You can just append an `<img>` on demand instead

Answer (score 0):

I created loading image by css ! But usually loading image is used in ajax call for long response ! For javascript is client language so it execute very faster so I tested with `setTimeout` for loading remove !

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  $(".loader").show();
   setTimeout(function(){
     showDivs(slideIndex += n);
   },1000);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  $(".loader").hide();
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    display:none;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
 <button class="" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
 <button class="" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
 
 <div class="mySlides">Test 1</div>
 <div class="mySlides">Test 2</div>
 <div class="mySlides">Test 3</div>
</div>
<div class='loader'></div>
```